# NetSuite Saved Search To Find Subsidiary NOT Set For Customer

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

We use multiple Subsidiaries; obviously every customer has at least one. Most have multiple, and I'm trying to get a list of all of the customers that don't have a particular subsidiary (call it 'XYZ').

The most obvious approach is to use:

```
Subsidiary : Name does not contain 'XYZ'
```

or, as a formula(numeric):

```
case when {msesubsidiary.namenohierarchy} != 'XYZ' then 1 end
```

That doesn't work because every customer has at least one subsidiary that isn't XYZ, so all customers satisfy the condition and get returned.

I've got a feeling the solution will involve counting the number of {msesubsidiary.namenohierarchy}s for each customer which = 'XYZ' and returning only the ones where that number is 0, but that's not an area I'm very knowledgeable on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a OneWorld system, but I've done the same thing looking for items that don't have a preferred bin in a given location, and works where you want to show any record where a sublist doesn't contain any desired value. And you're right in your thinking :

1. Make the Customer your first "Results" column, and set the summary type to "Group".
2. Set your "Standard" filters as required e.g excluding inactive, only certain sales reps, etc.
3. Create a  "Summary" filter :

- Type = Sum
- Field = Formula (Numeric)
- Formula = case when {msesubsidiary.namenohierarchy} = 'XYZ' then 1 else 0 end
- Condition = EQUALS 0

This creates a search, where for each customer, the subsidiary sublist is checked, and if ANY row matches XYZ then it sets the flag to one, and the condition (EQUALS 0) then only presents customers where NONE of the subsidiaries are XYZ.